# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies error in console

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run hello World in eclipse and i get this error in console

```
[2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] Versions found are:
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] Path: /Users/muhammadatif/Documents/workspace/HelloActivity1/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1]  Length: 995386
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1]  SHA-1: a13f8fe2c278737e2f0b6fcf00f6b2ae4034aacf
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] Path: /Users/muhammadatif/Documents/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1]  Length: 758727
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1]  SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
    [2014-11-18 23:50:05 - HelloActivity1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
    [2014-11-19 00:15:55 - BlogReader] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19'
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] Versions found are:
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] Path: /Users/muhammadatif/Documents/workspace/HelloActivity1/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1]  Length: 995386
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1]  SHA-1: a13f8fe2c278737e2f0b6fcf00f6b2ae4034aacf
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] Path: /Users/muhammadatif/Documents/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1]  Length: 758727
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1]  SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
    [2014-11-19 00:15:56 - HelloActivity1] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: the stack trace says it all. `Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list`

Comment: in your project,you have two android-support-v4.jar library.

Comment: You should use only one library in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution :

You just need to check that in your `appcompat_v7` lib project and your `HelloActivity1` project's `libs` folder has a same path for your `android-support-v4.jar`.

For ex,

if `HelloActivity1`  has a path

```
C://abc/android-support-v4.jar
```

then for `appcompat_v7` it must be the same path in `libs` folder.

Finally clean your project and build it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]clean your project and check all your dependency if you have dual support library.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jar android-support-v4.jar from your project also its reference from the buid path then clean and build the project. It will work.

Comment: i did exactly as you said but it didnt solve the problem. can you help me more?

Comment: exactly as mentioned in the question. I just updated with the lolipop update and this thing came up

Comment: then try compiling your app with api level 21.